# Set custom image on pin in map in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

i have a map view in my view controller, when i make a pin on the desired place i give my own image despite of the default image , but when i run and check the map it always shows default pin in my map instead of my image that i have passed. My code is this,

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{
MKAnnotationView *view=[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annoView"];
if (!view) {
    view=[[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annoView"];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }else{
    view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_marker.png"];
        view.canShowCallout=YES;
    }
}

return view;
```

}

```
 MapPin *pin=[[MapPin alloc]init];
    pin.title=loc[@"name"];
    pin.subtitle=nil;
    pin.coordinate=annoCordinate;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:pin.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to accomplish, you just need to subclass `MKAnnotationView` and add a custom image view to it. A good example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21813014/4659445).

In case the link dies, I have also included the code snippet below, please do show the OP some love though!

```
@interface TStickerAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@property(nonatomic) float stickerColor;

@end

@interface TStickerAnnotationView () {
    UIImageView *_imageView;
    TCircleView *_circleView;
}


@end

@implementation TStickerAnnotationView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // make sure the x and y of the CGRect are half it's
        // width and height, so the callout shows when user clicks
        // in the middle of the image
        CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(-30, -30, 60, 60);

        TCircleView* circleView = [[TCircleView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
        _circleView = circleView;
        [self addSubview:circleView];

        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

        // keeps the image dimensions correct
        // so if you have a rectangle image, it will show up as a rectangle,
        // instead of being resized into a square
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        _imageView = imageView;

        [self addSubview:imageView];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // when an image is set for the annotation view,
    // it actually adds the image to the image view
    _imageView.image = image;
}

- (void)stickerColor:(float)color {
    _circleView.green = color;
    [_circleView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: This code is for subclass? How the map class known about the image in subclass. @Jacob King

Comment: The issue is that it's an exact copy of somebody else's work.